# How much of the saddle rail is suiteable to use

Tags: safety, parts, saddle, bike-fit

Is it possible to safely set the seat to the max to get the saddle as far forward as it will go. Or should it only be clamped within the marked range 0 to 3.5? I have marked the points in red. The reason I ask is because I don't want the saddle to tilt forward while riding if I have it set to max.

[image]

Comment: In my experience there is no problem to go beyond the marks in either direction (some rails don't even have the marks) but it would be interesting to hear from someone else if those "limits" are actual safety limits or just loose recommendations...

Comment: I would think that the "max" marker means just that -- the maximum safe stop for the seat clamp, so you should be fine going all the way to "max". As long as it's not a lightweight racing saddle with very thin rails, I don't even  think there'd be a problem going beyond the max to use the whole horizontal portion of the rail, but you do so at your own risk. It seems that sliding forward to the front or back of your seat is going to put more stress on the rail than moving it  half a centimeter past the mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as no part of the clamp touches the rails outside the max lines, you should be safe.

The scale is simply there to help you. It would be nice if it ran right up to the max lines, but it might still be helpful depending on the size/design of your clamp.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that such an extreme position indicates a fit problem with the bike.  Maybe that's what you should attack first.